# return data from web service in one json string

Tags: php

i want to return data from a web services with php in one group json container. my below script gives me each of the data seperated like this

```
{"No":"01","Name":"JOSEPH"}{"No":"02","Name":"AMINU"}
```

But i wan it to return like this

```
[{"No":"01","Name":"JOSEPH","No":"02","Name":"AMINU"}]
```

below is my script

```
try{
    $service = new NTLMSoapClient($pageURL);
     $params = array('filter' => array( 
                        array('Field' => 'District_Name',  'Criteria' => '')
                                       ), 
                     'setSize' => 2); //setSize =0 will return all rows - Can cause performance issue with large results set!
     $result = $service->ReadMultiple($params); 
     $resultSet = $result->ReadMultiple_Result->customer;

    if (is_array($resultSet)) { 
        foreach($resultSet as $item) { 
            $data=array('No' => $item->No,'Name' => $item->Name);
            echo json_encode($data);
            } 
        } 
        else { 

            echo json_encode('record not found');
        }
    }
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<hr><b>ERROR: SoapException:</b> [".$e."]<hr>";
    echo "<pre>".htmlentities(print_r($service->__getLastRequest(),1))."</pre>";
}
```

Comment: echo json __once__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try you foreach with this.

```
try{
    $service = new NTLMSoapClient($pageURL);
     $params = array('filter' => array( 
                        array('Field' => 'District_Name',  'Criteria' => '')
                                       ), 
                     'setSize' => 2); //setSize =0 will return all rows - Can cause performance issue with large results set!
     $result = $service->ReadMultiple($params); 
     $resultSet = $result->ReadMultiple_Result->customer;

    if (is_array($resultSet)) { 
       $jsonArray = [];
       foreach($resultSet as $item) { 
       $data = array('No' => $item->No,'Name' => $item->Name);
       $jsonArray = array_merge($jsonArray, $data);
    } 
    echo json_encode($jsonArray);

        } 
        else { 

            echo json_encode('record not found');
        }
    }
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<hr><b>ERROR: SoapException:</b> [".$e."]<hr>";
    echo "<pre>".htmlentities(print_r($service->__getLastRequest(),1))."</pre>";
}
```

Comment: can you phrase it into my whole script?

Comment: I did it please see now.

Comment: i get errors in the script on this line $jsonArray = [] and  else {

Comment: I thought I have added one breaket extra please see now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148771/discussion-between-user6579134-and-ajay-korat).

Answer (score -1):

```
try{
    $service = new NTLMSoapClient($pageURL);
     $params = array('filter' => array( 
                        array('Field' => 'District_Name',  'Criteria' => '')
                                       ), 
                     'setSize' => 2); //setSize =0 will return all rows - Can cause performance issue with large results set!
     $result = $service->ReadMultiple($params); 
     $resultSet = $result->ReadMultiple_Result->customer;

    if (is_array($resultSet)) {
        $data = array();
        foreach($resultSet as $item) { 
            $data = $data + array('No' => $item->No,'Name' => $item->Name);
        } 
        echo json_encode($data);
    } 
    else {
        echo json_encode('record not found');
    }
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "<hr><b>ERROR: SoapException:</b> [".$e."]<hr>";
    echo "<pre>".htmlentities(print_r($service->__getLastRequest(),1))."</pre>";
}
```

Comment: Still these will generate  ```{"No":"01","Name":"JOSEPH"}{"No":"02","Name":"AMINU"}``` output like that because this will generate seprate arrray.